# Caching one big RDD or many small RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a large RDD (R) which i cut it into 20 chunks (C_1, C_2, ..., C_20) such that:

[image: Smaller chunks]

If the time it takes to cache only depends on the size of the RDD (e.g. 10 second per MB) then caching the individual chunks is better.

However, i suspect there is some additional overhead i'm not aware of, like seek time in case of persisting to disk.

So, my questions are:

- Are there any additional overheads when writing to memory?
- Is it better to **cache** (i.e. in memory) the large RDD (R) or the 20 individual chunks?

---

EDIT: To give some more context, i'm currently running the application on my computer but at the end it will run on a cluster consisting of 10 nodes, each of which has 8 cores. However, since we only have access to the cluster for a small amount of time, i wanted to already experiment locally on my computer.

From my understanding, the application won't need a lot of shuffling as i can partition it rather nicely, such that each chunk runs on a single node.
However, i'm still thinking about the partitioning, so it is not yet 100% decided.

Comment: Short answer. It depends. Lots of questions need to be asked in order to figure out the best course of action. Examples: How many nodes do you have in your cluster (parallelism). How many cores do you have per cluster node (parallelism)? What kinds of transformations are you going to perform (lots of shuffle)? When you say that you are chunking it do you mean that each chunk is partition size of 1? What is the number of partitions of the "large" rdd? To properly answer this question we would generally need to know about your setup and what you plan on doing with either the chunks or large rdd.

Comment: @Jeremy I updated my answer to give some more context. However, i cannot yet tell much about partitioning since i'm still thinking about "the best" strategy. Didn't thought there were some many aspects involved just for the purpose of caching (i.e. writing to memory).

Comment: I was referring more to the second question `Is it better to cache the large RDD or the 20 individual chucks?`

Comment: What is the size of the dataset that you will be caching?

Comment: The raw data set is 100 GB, however, i of course first transform it to remove the parts i don't need. Again, i have no idea how much space the remainder will take up. However, i do know that i can completely fit it into memory (since i have 10 nodes with 32 GB of RAM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark performs the computations in memory. So there is no real extra overhead when you cache data to memory. Caching to memory essentially says, reuse these intermediate results. The only issue that you can run into is having too much data in memory and then it spills to disk. There you will incur disk read time costs. `unpersist()` will be needed for swapping things out of memory as you get finished with the various intermediate results, if you run into memory limitations.

When determining where to cache your data you need to look at the flow of your data. If you read in a file and then filter it 3 times and write out each one of those filters separately, without caching you will end up reading in that file 3 times.

```
val data = spark.read.parquet("file:///testdata/").limit(100)
data.select("col1").write.parquet("file:///test1/")
data.select("col2").write.parquet("file:///test2/")
data.select("col3").write.parquet("file:///test3/")
```

If you read in the file, cache it, then you filter 3 times and write out the results. You will read in the file once and then write out each result.

```
val data = spark.read.parquet("file:///testdata/").limit(100).cache()
data.select("col1").write.parquet("file:///test4/")
data.select("col2").write.parquet("file:///test5/")
data.select("col3").write.parquet("file:///test6/")
```

The general test that you can use as to what to cache is, "Am I performing multiple actions on the same RDD?" If yes, cache it. In your example if you break the large RDD into chunks and the large RDD isn't cached you will most likely be recalculating the large RDD every time that you perform an action on it. Then if you don't cache the chunks and you perform multiple actions on those then you will have to recalculate those chunks every time.

> Is it better to cache (i.e. in memory) the large RDD (R) or the 20 individual chunks?

So to answer that, it all depends on what you are doing with each intermediate result. It looks like you will definitely want to properly repartition your large RDD according to the number of executors and then cache it. Then, if you perform more than one action on each one of the chunks that you create from the large RDD, you may want to cache those.

Comment: Interesting, in fact i asked this question because my original RDD is split into 20 chunks, and i perform only one action on the large RDD, so there is no need to cache it (except for fault tolerance maybe). However, i will perform several actions on the 20 chunks that i derive from my large RDD. So i was wondering whether i should cache only once (the large RDD) or cache the 20 smaller RDDs. From your answer i would derive i have to cache the 20 smaller RDDs and i can leave the large RDD uncached. Am i right? Thanks for the efforts you're putting in here!

Comment: Without seeing your code I'd say that would be correct. Also, I just want to make sure that we are both talking about the same thing when we say "action". [HERE](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) is the spark docs talking about actions.

Comment: Jep actions are what kick off the transformations, thanks for your help!